# Using PHP write an anagram function?

Tags: php, anagram

Using PHP write an anagram function? It should be handling different phrases and return boolean result.

Usage:

```
$pharse1 = 'ball';
$pharse2 = 'lbal';
if(is_anagram($pharse1,$pharse2)){
  echo $pharse1 .' & '. $pharse2 . ' are anagram';
}else{
  echo $pharse1 .' & '. $pharse2 . ' not anagram';
}
```

Comment: Have you answered your own question?

Comment: Yes. I answered my question

Comment: That's quick within a minute. Why do you think this question contributes to SO. In other words why did you place it.

Comment: This was a question I got in an interview. And I saw couple of answers but didn't find the right one.. So I placed my answer.

Comment: I think the next step will be to accept your answer. ;-)

Comment: Hahaaha... It won't let me do it today. So need to try that tomorrow. ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Radical: This was an interview question from my friend. I didn't found answer and push to stackover flow. But was keep  ing. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's simpler way

```
function is_anagram($a, $b) {
    return(count_chars($a, 1) == count_chars($b, 1));
}
```

example:

```
$a = 'argentino';
$b = 'ignorante';
echo is_anagram($a,$b);   // output: 1

$a = 'batman';
$b = 'barman';
echo is_anagram($a,$b);  // output (empty):
```

Answer (score 8):

```
function is_anagram($pharse1,$pharse2){
  $status = false;
  if($pharse1 && $pharse2){
   $pharse1=strtolower(str_replace(" ","", $pharse1));
   $pharse2=strtolower(str_replace(" ","", $pharse2));
   $pharse1 = str_split($pharse1);
   $pharse2 = str_split($pharse2);
   sort($pharse1);
   sort($pharse2);
   if($pharse1 === $pharse2){
   $status = true;
   } 
  }
  return $status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function check_anagram($str1, $str2) {
      if (count_chars($str1, 1) == count_chars($str2, 1)) {
           return "This '" . $str1 . "', '" . $str2 . "' are Anagram";
      }
      else {
          return "This two strings are not anagram";
      }

  }
    ECHO check_anagram('education', 'ducatione');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any answers which have addressed the fact that capital letters are different characters than lowercase to count_chars()

```
if (isAnagram('Polo','pool')) {
    print "Is anagram";
} else {
    print "This is not an anagram";
}

function isAnagram($string1, $string2)
{
    // quick check, eliminate obvious mismatches quickly
    if (strlen($string1) != strlen($string2)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Handle uppercase to lowercase comparisons
    $array1 = count_chars(strtolower($string1));
    $array2 = count_chars(strtolower($string2));

    // Check if 
    if (!empty(array_diff_assoc($array2, $array1))) {
        return false;
    } 
    if (!empty(array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2))) {
        return false;
    } 

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my variant :

```
public function is_anagram($wrd_1, $wrd_2) 
  {
  $wrd_1 = str_split ( strtolower ( utf8_encode($wrd_1) ) );
  $wrd_2 = str_split( strtolower ( utf8_encode($wrd_2) ) );

  if ( count($wrd_1)!= count($wrd_2) ) return false;
  if ( count( array_diff ( $wrd_1 ,$wrd_2) ) > 0 ) return false;

  return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Heheh little large but work as well :)

```
  public static function areStringsAnagrams($a, $b)
{
    //throw new Exception('Waiting to be implemented.');
    $a = str_split($a);

    $test = array();
    $compare = array();

    foreach ($a as $key) {
        if (!in_array($key, $test)) {
            array_push($test, $key);
            $compare[$key] = 1;
        } else {
            $compare[$key] += 1;
        } 
    }

    foreach ($compare as $key => $value) {
        if ($value !== substr_count($b, $key)) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```